# Google Cloud - Python SDK - firewall deployment verification

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have prepared automation in GCP cloud, automation is prepared in Python SDK. Script is deploying VPC firewall rules (I used documentation to prepare it - [GCP Python SDK firewall deployment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls/insert)). Automation works as expected, firewall rules are being created in the Google environment, but how can I check if the deployment completed successfully? I know that I can use `list` method to create list of existing firewall rules, then compere it with rules I wanted do deploy, but if there any native method to verify the deployment status?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. When you call the **firewalls.insert** REST API, a **resource** is returned. The resource includes information on progress and status. Edit your question and show your code and clarify the problem. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls/insert#response-body

Comment: Thanks, I used link You mentioned and prepared the code, pasted it in the Answer area.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I prepared that code, and it works in my environment.

```
import json
import time
import googleapiclient
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from colormodule import color

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

def create_vpc_firewall_rule(credentials, discovery, project, firewall_body):
    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    request = service.firewalls().insert(project=project, body=firewall_body)
    response = request.execute()
    return response

def firewall_body(traffic_direction_name, network_name, ports, json, project_name):
    rule_name_input = f'firewall-rule-test-{traffic_direction_name}'
    network_input = f'projects/{project_name}/global/networks/{network_name}'

    json_string = {
        "name": rule_name_input,
        "allowed": [
            {
                "IPProtocol": "tcp",
                "ports": ports
            }
        ],
        "network": network_input,
        "direction": "EGRESS",
        "destinationRanges": "192.168.0.23/32",
        "priority": 1000,
        "targetTags": [
            "testwindows"
        ]
    }
    data = json.dumps(json_string)
    return data

def wait_for_operation_fw_deployment(compute, project_id, operation, fw_rule_name, colors):
    print('')
    print('Waiting for operation to finish...')
    print('')
    while True:
        result = compute.globalOperations().get(
            project=project_id,
            operation=operation).execute()

        if result['status'] == 'DONE':
            print(f'Deployment of {colors.OKCYAN}%s{colors.ENDC} Firewall rule has been completed.'
                  % fw_rule_name)
            print('')
            time.sleep(2)
            if 'error' in result:
                raise Exception(result['Deployment has returned an error.'])
            return result

        time.sleep(2)

firewall_body = eval(firewall_body(traffic_direction_name,network_name, ports, json, project_name))
operation = create_vpc_firewall_rule(credentials, discovery, project_name, firewall_body)

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

wait_for_operation_fw_deployment(compute, project_id, operation['name'], fw_rule_name, colors)
```